# List models containing foreign key in a detail view

Tags: django, django-views

I would like to have a Django detail view that shows all the models containing a foreign key for the detail view page for that foreign key value, linked from a list view.

The model `ActivityID` contains a list of character id's (e.g. 'F1088HW'). There are several other models, each containing the contents of a storage facility, and each item has an ActivityID. So when F1088HW is clicked on, for example, a detail page should show all the facilities that has stuff from that ActivityID.

So far I have the following view based on various other SO questions:

```
class ActivityDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = ActivityID
    # context_object_name = 'library_set'  
    # Changed to 'activity' based on comments below
    # context_object_name = 'ativity'

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return models.objects.filter(activityid = pk)
```

And `ActivityID_detail.html`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Field Activity ID: {{ activity }} </h1>
<div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
<h4>Libraries</h4>
<dl>
{% for library in activity.library_set.all %}
  <dt><a href="{% url 'activity-detail' library.pk %}">{{library}}</a> ({{library.library_set.all.count}})</dt>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('activities/', views.ActivityIDsView.as_view(), name='activities'),
    path('activities/<int:pk>', views.ActivityDetailView.as_view(), name='activity-detail'),
]
```

But clicking on an ActivityID in the list view then returns:

> AttributeError at /catalog/activities/2429
>   module 'django.db.models'
>   has no attribute 'objects'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `models` module instead of your model.
Try:

```
return self.model.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

Comment: That solved the original error! Knew I was missing something obvious. Unfortunately now I get: `Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/activities/2429
Raised by: catalog.views.ActivityDetailView
No activity id found matching the query`

Comment: It means that such object with activityId=2429 wasn't found. Do you have any Activities that exists?

Comment: Hm... That one does exist. In the table it has id=2429 and activityid=F1088HW. Am I calling the URLs incorrectly?

Comment: In that case you need to have `id` in your filter. Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergey has pointed out, you're calling the wrong class. But actually the whole approach makes no sense. The detail in this view is the Activity. You don't want to filter the activities by activityid, you want to get the activity by ID and then get is related libraries.

The second part of that is done by the `activity.library_set.all` in the template, and the first part is what the DetailView would normally do - so you don't need that `get_queryset` method at all. You should remove it.

Comment: I can kind of wrap my mind around that. What would I do instead of `get_queryset`? The detail view loads without, but it's blank.

Comment: Set `context_object_name = "activity'` since that is the name you use in the template.

Comment: Without `get_queryset`, where is `library_set` coming from? Forgive me for being obtuse.

Comment: It's coming from `activity`, where you access it. It already exists. Adding `get_queryset` does not do anything here.

Comment: I must be missing something because nothing is coming up for `library_set`, even just a line like `{{ activity.library_set }}` or any variation of that.